# How can I reconfigure a jasmine spy in a test?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How can I reconfigure a jasmine spy in a test?

```
var spy = spyOn(foo, 'bar').and.returnValue(0);

//...

spy.and.returnValue(1); // This does not appear to work...
```

Comment: You could use 2 separate `it` to test it out. What's your usecase ?

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the actual spy method:

```
foo.bar.and.returnValue(1);
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.